# Quickbooks Webconnector Codeigniter Queue Ordering Issue

Tags: php, codeigniter, quickbooks

I have Quickbooks Webconnector connected to a standard CodeIgniter Webconnector Class Queue.

The problem: It has been pulling CustomerAdds out of the queue before SalesOrderAdds but something changed and now it is ordering what comes out of the queue differently so that the SalesOrderAdds are being pulled out first.

The question: Is there a way to dictate what order items are pulled out of the Queue by the WebConnector?

You probably need more information than that but I'm not sure what.  Let me know and I will provide it.

Comment: In the future, you should post your code. People are going to have a lot of trouble helping you unless you can post some code so they can see what you're doing.

Comment: I'm sorry.  I knew you were not going to be happy about that but I honestly couldn't think what to post.  I didn't want to post the whole Controller because that just seemed insane and I wasn't sure what parts were of value.  Looking at the enqueue function, however, I see where it is catching the priority.  I'll test that out and let you know.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The question: Is there a way to dictate what order items are pulled out of the Queue by the WebConnector?

Assuming you're using this open-source QuickBooks integration code from GitHub:

- https://github.com/consolibyte/quickbooks-php

You should be aware that the queue is a *priority queue* so you can specify the priority of things that run. Higher priorities run first.

- Documentation: http://wiki.consolibyte.com/wiki/doku.php/quickbooks_integration_php_consolibyte_webconnector#quickbooks_queueenqueue

Specifically if you do this:

```
// Queue up the customer with a priority of 10
$Queue->enqueue(QUICKBOOKS_ADD_CUSTOMER, $customer_id, 10);

// Queue up the sales order with a priority of 5
$Queue->enqueue(QUICKBOOKS_ADD_SALESORDER, $salesorder_id, 5);
```

Because higher priorities run first, that guarantees that the `CustomerAdd` (`priority=10`) will occur prior to the `SalesOrderAdd` (`priority=5`, which is lower than the `CustomerAdd`).